# Angularjs: Should I use mocks when Unit Testing a REST API dependent app?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

There are quite a bit of ambiguities i've found when researching the topic of Mocks, Stubs, & Spies specifically within Angularjs Unit Testing.

I need a straightforward answer to how and why I am supposed to implement unit tests the proper way (If there is one) on a REST-dependent Application.

Do i have to use mocks when testing, or is stubbing/spying suitable?

Is there a difference between spying and stubbing?

When I mock an http Request, do i need a separate mock for a function using that particular http Request?

How modularized do my tests need to be?

Take this unit test for example, using karma-jasmine testing framework:

```
    describe('PUT Request & editUser() Test', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            $httpBackend.whenPUT('http://localhost:24149/users/:id');
        });

        it('Should do PUT request to server', function() {

            $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'http://localhost:24149/users').respond();



            $scope.usersList[0] = user;
            $scope.selectedUser = 0;

            firstName =  user.firstName;
            lastName = user.lastName;
            phone = '222-222-2222';
            email = user.email;
            _id = 0001;


            $scope.newuserEditTest = {_id, firstName, lastName, phone, email};

            $httpBackend.expect('PUT', 'http://localhost:24149/users/1').respond();


            $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'templates/userprofile.html').respond();
            $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'templates/userslist.html').respond();
            $scope.editUser($scope.newuserEditTest);

            $httpBackend.flush();

            expect($scope.usersList[0].phone).toEqual('222-222-2222');
            dump("PUT SUCCESS: " + user.firstName + "'s Phone number changed from " + user.phone + " to " + $scope.usersList[0].phone);

        });
    });
```

I've been criticized for this test because i am testing the PUT request, and the editUser() function (which indirectly calls the PUT request). But wouldn't it make sense to test the function while mocking the REST requests?

If that is not the best method, then would I have to write a seperate mock for the service where the PUT request lies?

I assume that Mocks are the best practice when it comes to targeted individual units alone, but I have still seen examples without mocks, or with spies (or stubs) AND mocks and I don't understand which method is best practice.

Comment: hey Jake, if you are writing unit tests, remember you need to tests each part in isolation from the others. I mean, each service, each filter, each controller and each directive alone. AngularJS does a pretty good job allowing you to unit test them.
Use httpBackend mock to isolate those services that consumes a REST API.